# Можно ли найти и использовать код функции из стандартной библиотеки?

Tags: c++

Можно ли не вызывать функцию из библиотеки, а вставить в программу ее код.
Например вместо GetComputerName найти ее код в библиотеке и вставить в программу? Не знаю насколько скрыт код библиотек.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    char buffer[256];
    unsigned long size = 256;

    GetComputerName( buffer, &size );

    printf( "%s\n", buffer );

    system( "pause" );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А линковщик именно это и делает - для статических библиотек :)

Comment: GetComputerName - это функция не из стандартной библиотеки, а часть WinAPI, на сколько я знаю, исходный код WinAPI легально нельзя получить.

Comment: @rtuf20 Т.к. это WinAPI функция, то в любом случае, даже если у вас будет исходный код функции, то она в конечном итоге будет вызывать всё равно WinAPI функции, но более низкоуровневые. Если конкретно про функцию получения имени компьютера, то вместо функции GetComputerName можно просто прочитать запись в реестре Windows по пути `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName`, вполне возможно, что GetComputerName как раз это и делает внутри, читает запись реестра.Реестр можно читать стандартными функциями WinAPI,или найти/реализовать его формат и читать напрямую

Comment: Я бы использовал `std::getenv("COMPUTERNAME");` для получения имени компьютера.

Comment: @rtuf20 Есть так называемая бесплатная [ReactOS](https://reactos.org/) и [её исходники](https://github.com/reactos/reactos). Они у себя заявляют что полностью совместимы с Windows на бинарном уровне. Т.е. Windows приложения и DLL могут у них работать напрямую. Более того они все основные DLL винвдос тоже переписали. Вообщем это как бы открытая/бесплатная Windows, пока ещё не сильно развитая. Так вот раз они точно воспроизвели всё, значит где то они взяли исходники Windows, или точное описание работы WinAPI на бинарном уровне. Вот например [GetComputerName()](https://cutt.ly/ijdpbKN) функция.

Comment: Не могли бы привести пример как ее вызвать, с какими переменными? Пока что не понял.

Comment: @rtuf20 Как говорил @AlexeyVesker, если нужна именно только функцию получения имени компьютера то досточно сделать `printf("ComputerName: %s\n", std::getenv("COMPUTERNAME"));`, т.е. для получения имени компьютера достаточно кода `std::getenv("COMPUTERNAME")`. Кстати для использования функции `getenv` нужно включить модуль `#include <stdlib.h>`, хотя в вашем коде он уже включен. [Полное описание функции](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv) почитайте тоже. Также не забудьте вставить проверку, `getenv` вернёт 0-й указатель если не нашёл имени компьютера.

Comment: В идеале хотелось  чтобы при дизассемблировании не было видно вызова GetComputerName. Так же имя компьютера нужно будет сравнить с константой .

Comment: @rtuf20 Если вы используете `std::getenv("COMPUTERNAME")` функцию, то она точно никакого вызова GetComputerName не делает. Эта функция просто читает переменные окружения, находит переменную с именем COMPUTERNAME. У всех приложений доступны и часто используются эти переменные окружения. В мире Линукса так вообще на каждом шагу используются переменные окружения. [Вот можете почитать](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B) про переменные окружения.

Comment: Спасибо. Какие то следы остаются все же. mov     dword ptr [esp], offset aComputername ; 
  "COMPUTERNAME"

Comment: @rtuf20 Эти следы это не вызов функции GetComputerName, а просто изза имени строковой константы. Если вы хотите сокрыть это, тогда вам нужно простейшим образом зашифровать строку, цель такая чтобы в исходниках .cpp не было слова "COMPUTERNAME". Вы можете хоть в алфавите на +3 позиции каждую букву изменить, а потом в программе сделать обратное преобразование. Тогда строки "COMPUTERNAME" в финальном EXE не будет.

Comment: @rtuf20 Просто из любопытства, зачем так тщательно скрывать получение имени компьютера?

Comment: А как изменить каждую букву на 3 позиции?

Comment: Нужно чтобы мой код не работал в другом отделе. Поэтому проверяю имя компьютера.

Comment: @rtuf20 Вначале в отдельной программе делаем следующее `std::string s = "COMPUTERNAME"; for (auto & c: s) c += 3;   std::cout << s;`, Это выведет в консоль строку зашифрованную. Потом в самой программе вставляем эту строку, допустим она выглядит как "OIJCOIQYIUO", тогда в самой программ делаем обратное преобразование `std::string s = "OIJCOIQYIUO"; for (auto & c: s) c -= 3;`   и дальше используем эту строку `s` преобразованную всюду где раньше использовали "COMPUTERNAME", точнее используем `s.c_str()` т.к. нам нужна `char const *` строка. Кстати для std::string делаем `#include <string>`.

Comment: @Arty кстати, если подразумевается писать код на с++, то для использования `getenv` лучше подключить `cstdlib` вместо `stdlib.h`, последнее это скорее C-style

Comment: std::string s2="FRPSXWHUQDPH";for (auto & c: s2) c -= 3; пока что все просто отлично получилось! так можно и пути к файлам шифровать. Спасибо

Comment: @rtuf20 Да, такой способ может любую строку сокрыть. По крайней мере от новичков. Конечно это самый не стойкий шифр, но на первый взгляд в EXE файл этот мусор не понятен новичку и оригинальных строк тоже не будет видно. Также учтите, что просто так +3 прибавлять не всегда можно. Т.е. для латинских букв всегда можно, т.к. результат будет всегда в пределах ASCII. Но некоторые ASCII символы если прибавть 3 например символ `~` выйдет за пределы ASCII таблицы и уже будет не валидной UTF-8 строкой и могут быть проблемы в исходнике. Но усложнить шифр не сложно чтобы поддержать любую строку и символы.

Comment: @rtuf20 Решил все обсуждённые в комментариях предложения оформить как [мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228051/267338), кроме всего прочего также для научного интереса реализовал довольно стойкий шифр с 64-битным ключом, любопытно что о нём скажут, жду мнений!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привожу ранее обсуждённые в комментариях решения в виде моего ответа.

Ниже в коде я реализовал два самых простейших метода для получения имени компьютера без использования [GetComputerName](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcomputernamea) функции.

Первый вариант предложенный @AlexeyVesker это использование [std::getenv](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv) для чтения [переменной окружения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B) под именем `"COMPUTERNAME"`.

Второй вариант это чтение ключа реестра `"SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\ComputerName\\ComputerName"`, используя WinApi функции [RegOpenKeyExA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regopenkeyexa) и [RegQueryValueExA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regqueryvalueexa).

Если имя компьютера может содержать русские символы (или другие юникод) то нужно использовать варианты упомянутых выше функций с поддержкой юникода - [_wgetenv_s](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getenv-s-wgetenv-s?view=msvc-160), [RegOpenKeyExW](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regopenkeyexw), [RegQueryValueExW](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regqueryvalueexw).

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://rextester.com/FFQW83885)

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 1
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <windows.h>

#define ASSERT(cond) { if (!(cond)) throw std::runtime_error("Failed at line " + std::to_string(__LINE__)); }

inline static std::string GetComputerNameVar1() {
    auto r = std::getenv("COMPUTERNAME");
    ASSERT(r);
    return r;
}

inline static std::string GetComputerNameVar2() {
    HKEY hKey = 0;
    ASSERT(RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\ComputerName\\ComputerName", 0, KEY_READ, &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS);
    CHAR computer_name[1024] = {};
    DWORD buf_size = sizeof(computer_name);
    ASSERT(RegQueryValueExA(hKey, "ComputerName", 0, NULL, (LPBYTE)computer_name, &buf_size) == ERROR_SUCCESS);
    return computer_name;
}

int main() {
    try {
        SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);
        std::cout << GetComputerNameVar1() << std::endl;
        std::cout << GetComputerNameVar2() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    } catch (std::exception const & ex) {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Как было сказано, кроме сокрытия GetComputerName вызова, ещё нужно скрывать имена строк-констант `"COMPUTERNAME"` а также пути в реестре.

Для сокрытия строк можно использовать любой вид шифрования, просто для сокрытия от новичков (чтобы не было видно открытой строки в EXE файле) достаточно использовать самый простейший [криптографически не-стойкий](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) шифр, а именно [шифр Цезаря](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80_%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F), просто к каждому символу прибавляем например +3, зашифрованную строку сохраняем в константу, и потом в коде при использовании строковой константы делаем обратную (-3) операцию.

Пример кода для зашифрования ([попробовать онлайн!](https://tio.run/##RYyxCsIwFEX3fMWlgrSIk1uSFop0rIroB4TXWgJtUvqSSfz2WHToGc@5XJrnI43GDSntrKMxdj209RyW3kyV2NxqrBsqYV3AZKzLC7wFVjh0Uv4rGCWy87W9PR/N/VK3TaZ@m5dfkJsYPPYgCS5AOJQ4qe2BfAzQGqzEJ6Uv)):

```
std::string s = "COMPUTERNAME";  for (auto & c: s) c += 3;
std::cout << s;
```

Получаем на выходе строку `"FRPSXWHUQDPH"`, затем в использующем его коде делаем обратную операцию ([попробовать онлайн!](https://tio.run/##RYyxCoMwFEX3fMXFQtHBqVsSnYo42pbSruFp5YEmYpKp9NtTaQfPeM7l0rKUNBk7pnRgS1PsB2h2PqyDmWuxu82wHWvBNmA2bPMCb4ENH3op/xUeFbLm2t2ej/Z@OXdtpn6bl1uRmxgcjiAJX4BQVjip/YFcDNAaXolPSl8)):

```
std::string s = "FRPSXWHUQDPH";  for (auto & c: s) c -= 3;
std::cout << s;
```

получаем на выходе `"COMPUTERNAME"`.

Аналогично шифруется и путь в реестре из первой программы выше. И любые строки использованные в программе и необходимые к сокрытию.

---

**PS**

Просто ради интереса я решил реализовать относительно стойкий шифр, для шифрования строк. Он использует 64-битный ключ, 32-битную синхропосылку, 16-битную имитовставку (усечённый [Adler-32](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adler-32)) и является шифром [простого гаммирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) используя сгенерированную случайную последовательность с помощью псевдо-случайного датчика [64-битного вихря Мерсенна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%80%D1%8C_%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Если 64-битный ключ хорошо запрятать в программе, например несколько раз сделать математические преобразования, так чтобы в EXE дампе не было его возможно найти в исходном виде, то кроме как дизассемблирования EXE либо полного 2^64 перебора пространства ключей, скорее всего уже не взломаешь шифр.

Приведённый код ниже может быть использован не только для шифрования строк, но и любых (включая бинарные) данные, только нужно учесть что шифр не слишком стойкий, т.к. всего 64-битный ключ, также синхропосылка всего 32 бит (значит на одном ключе нельзя шифровать больше чем 2^16-2^20 различных строк). Но для сокрытия от лишних глаз шифр вполне годится и занимает не много строк кода (и может быть просто вставлен в код).

Также шифр почти без изменений я могу улучшить до 128-битного (или сколько надо) ключа, это не сложно, если такой интерес будет.

Код ниже следует использовать так - 1) вначале при первом запуске генерируем 64-битный ключ, это то что выводится в первой строке в консоле, `Random Encryption Key: .....`. 2) сгенерированный ключ вбиваем в код например `auto key = 0x71A1B4D23BC793E1ULL;` 3) дальше на втором запуске шифруем все нужные нам строки, просто вызываем для примера `Decrypt(key, Encrypt(key, "COMPUTERNAME"))` (здесь Decrypt не обязателен, просто для доп контроля что зашифрованная строка успешно расшифровывается) 4) вызов функции зашифрования выведет в консоль зашифрованную последовательность 5) эту последовательность вбиваем в использующий строки код как например `auto s_COMPUTERNAME = Decrypt(key, {0x78, 0xBF, 0xA3, 0x83, 0xE7, 0x10, 0x9C, 0xAE, 0x85, 0xF7, 0x07, 0x0D, 0x22, 0x20, 0xB7, 0x9F, 0xFA, 0x7E, });`. 6) всё, s_COMPUTERNAME это строка типа std::string содержащая исходную "COMPUTERNAME" строку.

Если есть предложения, что не так в этом шифре, сообщайте.

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://godbolt.org/z/KEn1qh)

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstring>

inline uint64_t GenRandomU64() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937_64 rg((uint64_t(rd()) << 32) + uint64_t(rd()));
    rg.discard(1000);
    return rg();
}

template <typename T>
inline T UnalignedRead(void const * ptr) {
    T v = T();
    memcpy(&v, ptr, sizeof(T));
    return v;
}

template <typename T>
inline void UnalignedWrite(void * ptr, T const & v) {
    memcpy(ptr, &v, sizeof(T));
}

inline void CheckSystemRequirements() {
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits == 8, "Only 8-bit byte is supported!");
    static_assert(
        std::numeric_limits<uint8_t>::digits == 8 &&
        std::numeric_limits<uint16_t>::digits == 16 &&
        std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::digits == 32 &&
        std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::digits == 64, "Uints of unsupported bit sizes!");
    uint64_t x = 0x0123456789ABCDEFULL;
    if (UnalignedRead<uint8_t>(&x) != 0xEF)
        throw std::runtime_error("Only little endian systems are supported!");
}

inline std::vector<uint8_t> Encrypt(uint64_t key, std::string const & s) {
    CheckSystemRequirements();
    uint32_t iv = uint32_t(GenRandomU64());
    std::vector<uint8_t> r((uint8_t*)&iv, ((uint8_t*)&iv) + sizeof(iv));
    std::mt19937_64 rng(key + iv);
    rng.discard(1000);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < (s.size() + 2 + 7) / 8; ++i) {
        auto w = rng();
        r.insert(r.end(), (uint8_t*)&w, ((uint8_t*)&w) + sizeof(w));
    }
    r.resize(sizeof(iv) + s.size() + 2);
    uint32_t mac0 = 1, mac = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
        mac0 = (mac0 + uint8_t(s[i])) % 65521; mac = (mac + mac0) % 65521;
        r[sizeof(iv) + i] ^= uint8_t(s[i]);
    }
    UnalignedWrite<uint16_t>(r.data() + r.size() - 2, UnalignedRead<uint16_t>(r.data() + r.size() - 2) ^ uint16_t(mac));
    std::cout << "Encrypted \"" << s << "\": {";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < r.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << std::uppercase << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << size_t(r[i]) << ", ";
    std::cout << "}" << std::endl;
    return r;
}

inline std::string Decrypt(uint64_t key, std::vector<uint8_t> const & v) {
    CheckSystemRequirements();
    uint32_t iv = 0;
    if (v.size() < sizeof(iv) + 2)
        throw std::runtime_error("Decryption failed, data size less than IV + MAC size!");
    iv = UnalignedRead<uint32_t>(v.data());
    auto s_size = v.size() - sizeof(iv) - 2;
    // Almost same as in Encrypt
    std::vector<uint8_t> r((uint8_t*)&iv, ((uint8_t*)&iv) + sizeof(iv));
    std::mt19937_64 rng(key + iv);
    rng.discard(1000);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < (s_size + 2 + 7) / 8; ++i) {
        auto w = rng();
        r.insert(r.end(), (uint8_t*)&w, ((uint8_t*)&w) + sizeof(w));
    }
    r.resize(sizeof(iv) + s_size + 2);
    uint32_t mac0 = 1, mac = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s_size; ++i) {
        r[sizeof(iv) + i] ^= v[sizeof(iv) + i];
        mac0 = (mac0 + r[sizeof(iv) + i]) % 65521; mac = (mac + mac0) % 65521;
    }
    if ((uint16_t(mac) ^ UnalignedRead<uint16_t>(r.data() + r.size() - 2)) != UnalignedRead<uint16_t>(v.data() + v.size() - 2))
        throw std::runtime_error("Decryption failed, wrong MAC!");
    return std::string((char*)(r.data() + sizeof(iv)), s_size);
}

int main() {
    try {
        std::cout << "Random Encryption Key: 0x" << std::hex << std::uppercase << GenRandomU64() << "ULL" << std::endl;
        // Example of random encryption key generated by line of code above.
        auto key = 0x71A1B4D23BC793E1ULL;
        Decrypt(key, Encrypt(key, "COMPUTERNAME"));
        // Example of encrypted string generated by line of code above.
        auto s_COMPUTERNAME = Decrypt(key, {0xE5, 0x19, 0xF4, 0x41, 0x54, 0xBC, 0xBB, 0x45, 0x31, 0x13, 0xD4, 0x6B, 0x64, 0x3C, 0xFF, 0xBC, 0xA6, 0x3E, });
        std::cout << "Decrypted: \"" << s_COMPUTERNAME << "\"" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    } catch (std::exception const & ex) {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Один из примеров вывода:

```
Random Encryption Key: 0x7B0BD8ACD1E306D7ULL
Encrypted "COMPUTERNAME": {0x82, 0xB7, 0xFE, 0xF2, 0x09, 0xB0, 0x49, 0x79, 0x8E, 0x2C, 0x56, 0x24, 0x53, 0x0D, 0x3B, 0x27, 0xC1, 0x10, }
Decrypted: "COMPUTERNAME"
```

Comment: **1)** `GenRandomU64() {...}`: В чём смысл "прокачивания" значений полученных от `std::random_device` через `std::mt19937_64`? Пытаетесь получить "более случайные" числа? Уверены, что ваш алгоритм не ухудшает результат работы `std::random_device`? Например, если бы вы использовали 32-битный вихрь Мерсенна вот так: `return std::mt19937( std::random_device{}() )()`, то никогда бы не получили значение `7` или `13`. Да у вас 64 битный вихрь и вы отбрасываете 1000 значений, но как это влияет на итоговое значение?

Comment: **2)** `(uint8_t*)&iv`: если тип `uint8_t` не есть псевдоним для `unsigned char`, то нарушение strict aliasing => UB. **3)** `key + iv`: если результирующий тип есть `int`, и результирующее значение не представимо типом `int`, то UB. **4)** `for (size_t i = 0; i < (s.size() + 2 + 7) / 8; ++i)`: если `s.size()` возвращает 32-битное значение типа `unsigned int`, равное `2**32 - 2 - 7`, то цикл не совершит ни одной итерации. **5)** `*(uint16_t*)(r.data() + r.size() - 2)`: **a)** возможное нарушение требований по выравниванию => результат каста указателя не специфицируется.

Comment: **b)** если тип `uint16_t` не есть псевдоним для `unsigned char`, то нарушение strict aliasing => UB. **6)** `*(uint32_t const *)v.data()`: **a)** возможное нарушение требований по выравниванию => результат каста указателя не специфицируется. **b)** если тип `uint32_t` не есть псевдоним для `unsigned char`, то нарушение strict aliasing => UB.

Comment: @wololo Я предположил что любой псевдослучайный генератор чисел включая вихрь мерсенна может просто хорошо перемешать заданную входную величину, т.е. если случайность от random_device по какой то причине например не все 32 бита заполнила а скажем 24 и сверху нули, или может не все 32 бита равновероятны если случайность скажем пришла от датчика времени, то даже из такой случайности вихрь мерсенна после пропуска 1000 значений даст все 64 бита равновероятные. Другим словом я не столько хотел сделать более случайное что то а более перемешанное и равновероятное по битам.

Comment: @wololo Понятно что если случайность входная не очень случайна и не очень равновероятна, то вихрь мерсенна степень предсказуемости входа не уменьшит, любой хакер может применить повторно те же шаги, предсказать начальную случайность если она была не очень случайна и применить мои шаги вихря и получит ключ.

Comment: @wololo Не понимаю в ваших комментариях фразу `если тип uint32_t не есть псевдоним для unsigned char, то нарушение strict aliasing`, как uint32_t может быть псевдонимом для unsigned char? первый всегда 4 байта, последний всегда 1 байт.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118143/discussion-between-arty-and-wololo).